# Max number of elements vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I was looking to see how many elements I can stick into a vector before the program crashes. When running the code below the program crashed with a bad alloc at i=90811045, aka when trying to add the 90811045th element. My question is: Why 90811045?

it is:

- not a power of two
- not the value that vector.max_size() gives
- the same number both in debug and release
- the same number after restarting my computer
- the same number regardless of what the value of the long long is

**note: I know I can fix this by using vector.reserve() or other methods, I am just interested in where 90811045 comes from.**

code used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<long long> myLongs;

    std::cout << "Max size expected : " << myLongs.max_size() << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 160000000; i++) {
        myLongs.push_back(i);

        if (i % 10000 == 0) {
            std::cout << "Still going!      : " << i << "   \r";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

extra info:
I am currently using 64 bit windows with 16 GB of ram.

Comment: It is derived from factors, like maximum amount of ram available to processes, that's highly specific to your operating system and the C++ library. The actual number is completely meaningless on its own.

Comment: you ran out of memory in your process, it depends what else was eating up memory, how big long long is,.... I got  159990000 - a totally different number on vs2022 64 bit

Comment: A more meaningful check would be what the `capacity` is before the program crashes. That number at least has some meaning

Comment: I think you made the same mistake as me. I accidently debugged the 32 bit application in Visual Studio 2019 and it stopped at: `90810000`. For a 32 bit application you have I believe a 2GB address space by default and need to use the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker switch to get 3 or 4GB however the maximum single allocation size is limited smaller than that because of address space fragmentation.

Comment: On a 64 bit application in Visual Studio 2019  I got: `159990000`

Answer (score 1):

> Why 90811045?

It's probably just incidental.

That vector is not the only thing that uses memory in your process. There is the execution stack where local variables are stored. There is memory allocated by for buffering the input and output streams. Furthermore, the global memory allocator uses some of the memory for bookkeeping.

90811044 were added succesfully. The vector implementation (typically) has a deterministic strategy for allocating larger internal buffer. Typically, it multiplies the previous capacity by a constant factor (greater than 1). Hence, we can conclude that `90811044 * sizeof(long long) + other_usage` is consistently small enough to be allocated successfully, but `(90811044 * sizeof(long long)) * some_factor + other_usage` is consistently too much.